# Reverse the string obtained from the user also before printing convert it to title format

Tags: python, list

I am new here and this is my first programming question:
Write a Python program that asks the user for their full name and prints it in a standard form where: the first and last names are lower case except for the first letter in the name and the last name (surname) is printed first, followed by a comma and space and then the first (given) name.  You may assume that the user always gives their given name first followed by their surname and that only two names are given separated by a space character.  Example run:

Program to standardize the listing of people’s names

Enter your full name: Elon MUSK
The standardized listing is: Musk, Elon

Hint 1: Check out the string methods title() and find()

Hint 2: Find the space character and use string slicing to grab the given name and surname.

my attempt:

```
print("Program to standardize the listing of people’s names\n")

name=input('Enter your full name: ')

x=name.split()

print("The standardized listing is: "+str.title(x[1])+", "+str.title(x[0]))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `find()` to get the position of the space character:

```
space_position = name.find(' ')
```

Then use slicing to separate into first name and last name:

```
# first name is everything up to (but not including) the space
first_name = name[:space_position]

# last name is everything after the space
last_name = name[space_position+1:]
```